# Generalizing the Reflection Principle of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $

Tags: set-theory

The Reflection Principle states that for any finite list $ \phi_{1},\ldots,\phi_{n} $ of axioms of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, we have
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
(\exists c) \!
\left(
\text{“$ c $ is countable and transitive”} \land
\left( \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}^{c} \right)
\right),
$$
where $ \phi_{i}^{c} $ denotes the relativization of $ \phi_{i} $ to $ c $ for each $ i \in \{ 1,\ldots,n \} $.

What I would like to know is, if $ S $ is a set of sentences in the first-order language of set-theory, and if $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $ is consistent, then is the following assertion also true?

> For any finite list $ \phi_{1},\ldots,\phi_{n} $ of sentences taken from $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $, we have
>   $$
> \mathsf{ZFC} + S \vdash
> (\exists c) \!
> \left(
> \text{“$ c $ is countable and transitive”} \land
> \left( \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}^{c} \right)
> \right).
> $$

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes. And you can replace ZFC with ZF. Just use the Lowenheim-Skolem construction in ZF+S, the same as you do in ZFC.

Comment: It suffices to note that ZF actually proves the more general conditional claim for any $\phi_0,...,\phi_n\in\mathcal L_\in$: if $\phi_0 \wedge,...,\wedge\phi_n$, then there is a $c$ such that.... Trivially, any extension of ZF also proves that claim.

Comment: Don't you need AC to obtain a _countable_ $c$?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Sorry, my bad. For my claim, I think you're right: the conditional claim for countable transitive models implies dependant choice for $\Delta_1^{ZF}$ relations (without parameters). Anyway, my response works for ZFC, which is what the OP was after.

Comment: @user254665: In light of what Pedro has mentioned, I believe that in order to apply the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem, one must assume the Axiom of Dependent Choice at least. Hence, working in $ \mathsf{ZF} $ alone does not appear to work. In any case, thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Transcendental. I think so too.

Comment: @GME: The downwards LS is equivalent to DC over ZF. Not just for $\Delta_1$ relations. And the usual proof is to find some $V_\theta$ satisfying the axioms and take a countable elementary submodel of that. Which will, again, lead you to a full DC situation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know. What wasn't clear to me is that the (conditional form of the) OP's reflection principle implied that. Does it? (I.e. for sentences $\phi$: if $\phi$, then there is a countable transitive $c$ such that $\phi^c$).

Comment: @GME: It's unclear to me that this implies DC (over ZF, that is, in ZFC, this is trivial). But I don't see how to prove reflection principles like this without going through $V_\theta$ and then a countable elementary submodel.

Comment: The question was inspired by the following observation: If we were to establish the equiconsistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $ with some other axiom collection by forcing over a countable transitive model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $, then the generalized version of the Reflection Principle, as stated above, would allow us to conveniently translate the forcing proof into a finitistic proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZF}{\mathrm{ZF}}$I would like to state a version of the Reflection Principle under $\ZF$ that (at least to me) makes the point a little clearer. Informally, it says that the truth value each every **formula** (not just sentences) gets reflected in many transitive sets.

For this, recall the [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe#Definition) $V_\alpha$ given by iterated powersets. The precise statement of this version says:

> **Theorem.** ($\ZF$) For each formula $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, sets $a_1,\dots,a_n$  and each ordinal $\beta$ with $\bar a = a_1,\dots,a_n\in V_\beta$, there exists $\alpha>\beta$ such that
>   $$V\models\phi(\bar a) \iff V_\alpha\models \phi(\bar a).$$

Here, as usual, $V$ is the universe of sets. Actually, one can show that for each $\phi$, there is a [club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_set) of ordinals $\alpha$ for which the conclusion holds.

In the case of $\phi$ a sentence that holds in $V$ (that is, any consequence of the axioms you put to the left of $\vdash$), you obtain immediately your conclusion$^1$ (without the “countable” adjective). Some care is needed here since intuitively $V_\alpha\models\phi$ is “equivalent” to $\phi^{V_\alpha}$ but the last expression is not a formula. But perhaps you can fill the gaps.

Finally, using the [downward Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part) you may obtain a countable elementary submodel (*choose* some Skolem functions, take the closure, using that *countable union of countable sets is countable* verify that it is indeed countable). This is a submodel of a well founded model, hence well founded, and you can [collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma) it to a transitive model.

I hope this helps; actually, the idea marked with $(^1)$ contains the meat of my answer, since that's how I managed to understand the point of your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Pedro. It allowed me to answer my question in its entirety.

Comment: @Transcendental You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought that I should convert Pedro’s response into a fully direct answer to my question.

---

Theorem Scheme 7.4 in Nik Weaver’s book [*Forcing for Mathematicians*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814566004) states the following:

> For any sentence $ \phi $ in the first-order language of set theory (henceforth called “LOST”), we have
>   $$
> \mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
> (\exists c)
> (“\text{$ c $ is countable and transitive}” \land (\phi \iff \phi^{c})).
> $$

This is very similar to the version of the Reflection Principle stated by Pedro.

Let $ S $ be a set of LOST-sentences such that $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $ is consistent, and let $ (\phi_{i})_{i \in [n]} $ be a finite list of sentences taken from $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $. Basic logic gives us
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + S \vdash \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}. \qquad (\clubsuit)
$$
By the quoted result, we have
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
(\exists c) \!
\left(
“\text{$ c $ is countable and transitive}” \land
\left(
\bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i} \iff
\left( \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i} \right)^{c}
\right)
\right).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
(\exists c) \!
\left(
“\text{$ c $ is countable and transitive}” \land
\left(
\bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i} \iff \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}^{c}
\right)
\right).
$$
As $ \mathsf{ZFC} + S $ is clearly at least as strong as $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, it follows that
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + S \vdash
(\exists c) \!
\left(
“\text{$ c $ is countable and transitive}” \land
\left(
\bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i} \iff \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}^{c}
\right)
\right). \qquad (\spadesuit)
$$
Finally, applying *modus ponens* to $ (\clubsuit) $ and $ (\spadesuit) $, we obtain
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + S \vdash
(\exists c) \!
\left(
“\text{$ c $ is countable and transitive}” \land
\left( \bigwedge_{i = 1}^{n} \phi_{i}^{c} \right)
\right).
$$